# react native AwesomeAlert customView throwing an error

Tags: react-native, plugins, alert, custom-view

I am using `react-native-awesome-alerts` plugin to show an alert in my screen. I've created a custom view for the alert but it throws me this error

> Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function! (Trying to add a 'RCTRawText [text: }]' to a 'RCTView')

My code is like this :

```
_displayNotifyAlert(){
  if(this.state.notifyAlert == true){
    return (
      <AwesomeAlert
        show={true}
        title="Service Cancellation"
        message="Tell the shop why are you cancelling their services."
        messageStyle={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
        customView={this.renderCustomAlertView()}
        showCancelButton={true}
        showConfirmButton={true}
        cancelText="Cancel"
        confirmText="Cancel Service"
        confirmButtonColor={Colors.default}
        onCancelPressed={() => this._closeNotifyAlert()}
        onConfirmPressed={() => this._cancelServices()}
      />
    )
  }
}

renderCustomAlertView = () => (
  <View style={[ AppStyles.input ]}>
    <TextInput
      placeholder="Write your reason briefly."
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      style={{ textAlignVertical: 'top', height: 100 }}
      numberOfLines={5}
      multiline={true}
      maxLength={200}
      onChangeText={(cancel_reason) => this.setState({cancel_reason})} />
    }
  </View>
)
```

If I remove this line `customView={this.renderCustomAlertView()}`, the error will disappear. I don't see any incorrect code that I put in the `renderCustomAlertView` function. So I cannot track down the cause of the error. Is there anybody that faced the same problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extra "}" at the end of your `renderCustomAlertView` function. Change this function to the following and it should work:

```
renderCustomAlertView = () => (
  <View style={[ AppStyles.input ]}>
    <TextInput
      placeholder="Write your reason briefly."
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      style={{ textAlignVertical: 'top', height: 100 }}
      numberOfLines={5}
      multiline={true}
      maxLength={200}
      onChangeText={(cancel_reason) => this.setState({cancel_reason})} />
  </View>
)
```

Comment: Oh that's just a small matter and I missed to check it. By the way, thank you for noticing it! :)

Comment: @Emerald Glad I could help :]

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment in your post because of low reputations so I'm making it as an answer.
As per my knowledge in react native and based on your code You are missing return in renderCustomAlertView .

so your code must be something like

```
   renderCustomAlertView = () => {
             return(
              <View style={[ AppStyles.input ]}>
                  <TextInput
                     placeholder="Write your reason briefly."
                     underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                     style={{ textAlignVertical: 'top', height: 100 }}
                     numberOfLines={5}
                     multiline={true}
                     maxLength={200}
                     onChangeText={(cancel_reason) => this.setState({cancel_reason})} />
           </View>
     )
   }
```